# CSS element prevent moving when border is added

Tags: css

How do I prevent elements from shifting when I add a border to them?
example:

```
 p:hover
    {
    border:1px solid red;
    }

    p
    {
     border:none;
    }
```

But is not working

Comment: This is one way: http://jsfiddle.net/x9FP3/1/ (There might be better. )

Comment: god dammit i feel so stupid now

Answer (score 1):

Always give them a border, just make it transparent when it's not hovered:

```
p {
    border:1px solid transparent;
}
p:hover {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/aj32B/)

Of course it's *one* answer, your question can be answered a number of ways.

Answer (score 1):

```
p {
  border:1px solid transparent;
}
```